Azure Function OrchestrationTrigger Parallel Issue
I am building an Azure Orchestration Function App that has four different functions. The first function is a start task function that removes containers inside a Cosmos DB database. The second function, which I am having a problem with, scans a Cosmos DB container that consists of multiple links and extracts some of the links. Then, it saves the links inside a new Cosmos DB container.
Inside the Orchestration Function, I am using a for-loop that runs this function 4 times with different parameters, in reality, I will have around 9 or more: I want the app takes A, B, C, D and finishes all. Now it is going back and forth.
Thank you for your help
This is my orchestration function:
[Function(nameof(CosmosDBFunction))]
public async Task<string> RunOrchestrator(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
{
    ILogger logger = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger(nameof(CosmosDBFunction));
    logger.LogInformation("----Function Started-----");

    try
    {
        await context.CallActivityAsync("StartupTask");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogError($"Error happened StartupTask: {ex.Message}");
    }

    var parallelTasks = new List<Task<string>>();
    var sites = new List<string>() {
        "A", "B", "C", "D"
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < sites.Count; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            var task = context.CallActivityAsync<string>("ScanSafetoAContainer", sites[i]);
            parallelTasks.Add(task);
        }
        catch (TaskFailedException ex) when (ex.InnerException is CosmosException cosmosException)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Error calling for site {sites[i]}: {ex.Message}");
        }
        catch (TaskFailedException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Error calling {sites[i]}: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(parallelTasks);

    context.CallActivityAsync("SaveToAContainer");

    try
    {
        logger.LogInformation("----Function B Started-----");
        await context.CallActivityAsync("SaveToXContainer");
    }
    catch (TaskFailedException ex)
    {
        logger.LogError($"Error happened : {ex.Message}");
    }

    try
    {
        logger.LogInformation("----Function clinksToBlinks Started-----");
        await context.CallActivityAsync("SaveToYContainer");
    }
    catch (TaskFailedException ex) 
    { 
        logger.LogError($"Error happened: {ex.Message}");
    }

    logger.LogInformation("----Function Finished-----");

    try
    {
        logger.LogInformation($"Operation is completed");
        return "Operation is completed";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return $"Operation is completed: exception at the end line {ex.Message}";
    }
}

This is the function that has been called inside the loop:
[Function(nameof(Something))]
[CosmosDBOutput(databaseName: "DB", containerName: "AB",
      Connection = "CosmosConnection"
     , CreateIfNotExists = true, PartitionKey = "/something")]
public async Task<string> SaveAToContainer
    ([ActivityTrigger] string site,
     FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    ConcurrentBag<Object> links = new ConcurrentBag<Object>();
    ILogger _logger = executionContext
                           .GetLogger(nameof(Something));

    var container = await CreateContainer();
    var client = _httpClientFactory;
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);

    using FeedIterator<object> object = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Page>()
        .Where(s => s.prop == prop)
        .ToFeedIterator<Object>();

    while (pages.HasMoreResults)
    {
        long counter = 0;

        foreach (var page in await pages.ReadNextAsync())
        {
            string href = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage responseFromUrl = await client.GetAsync(page.Url);
                var htmlContent = await responseFromUrl.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(htmlContent);

                HtmlNode divNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='ga-maincontent']");
                HtmlNodeCollection anchorTags = doc.DocumentNode
               .SelectNodes("//div[@id='ga-maincontent']//a[@href]");

                if (anchorTags != null)
                {
                    foreach (HtmlNode anchorTag in anchorTags)
                    {
                        href = anchorTag.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);

                        if (href.StartsWith("http"))
                        {
                            long uniqueId = Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
                            links.Add(new Link
                            {
                                Id = $"{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}{Interlocked.Increment(ref counter)}",
                                 PropA= something
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                links.Add(new Link
                {
                    Id = $"{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}{Interlocked.Increment(ref counter)}",
                    PropA= something
                });

                _logger.LogInformation($"Http request exception :" +
                    $" Message :{ex.Message} | Status Code {ex.Source} | {ex.Source} ");
            }

            //if (i >= pages.) break;
        }
    }

    string scannedLinks = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        ss = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(links);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Parallel Func Insert Links : {ex.Message} ");
    }

    return ss;
} 

I used to use the list instead of ConcurrentBag, but then I thought it is not thread safe why the apps is not executing as I am expecting. However, I feel that I am using async and await keywords nicely to make sure that the app run and waits for the tasks to complete.
What I really want to do is: when I loop through the task: A, B, C, and D will be completed and all be ready saved to cosmos db, and then we go to the third function.
Any suggestion of what I am doing wrong is much appreciated.

Can you describe in more detail how your app is behaving not as you expect?

Sometimes the app never finishes all tasks and stays stuck. Sometimes, it comes out of the loop and goes back again to finish.

I solved the issue by changing the connection mode from direct mode to gateway mode.
